# i want to select all the values less than 50 how can i do that

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
match_records = soup.find_all('td',class_ = 'rankings-block__banner--matches')
match_records

records = []
for i in match_records:
    records.append(i.text)
records

match_records2 = soup.find_all('td',class_ = 'table-body__cell u-center-text')
match_records2
for i in match_records2:
    records.append(i.text)
print(records)
```

output:-

```
['17', '32', '3,793', '28', '3,244', '32', '3,624', '25', '2,459', '27', '2,524', '30', '2,740', '30', '2,523', '32', '2,657', '17', '1,054', '7', '336', '25', '1,145', '11', '435', '20', '764', '7', '258', '11', '330', '9', '190', '14', '232', '6', '97', '9', '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your code the variable `records` holds a list of strings.

You can either add 'if' statements when filling it, to ensure only 50+ values get in, or, you can analyze the list after filling it.

Notice the difference between `str` and `int` objects, and notice the commas `,` (see 1,234) you'll need to get rid off.

I'd add the following snippet after your code:

```py
fixed_records = [int(record.replace(',','')) for record in records]
```

This will create the wanted list.
Note that this is not the most efficient (memory + time), but it is simple to use and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with the help of `lambda` expression and `filter`.

```
records = list(filter(lambda a: int(a.replace(',', '')) < 50, records))
```

Do you need string again?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement:

```
match_records = soup.find_all('td',class_ = 'rankings-block__banner--matches')
match_records
records = []
for i in match_records:
    if (a:=int(i.text.replace(',', '')) < 50:
        records.append(a)
print(records)

match_records2 = soup.find_all('td',class_ = 'table-body__cell u-center-text')
match_records2
for i in match_records2:
    if (a:=int(i.text.replace(',', '')) < 50:
        records.append(a)
print(records)
```

With the walrus operator. If your Python version is under 3.8, use:

```
match_records = soup.find_all('td',class_ = 'rankings-block__banner--matches')
match_records
records = []
for i in match_records:
    a = int(i.text.replace(',', ''))
    if a < 50:
        records.append(a)
print(records)

match_records2 = soup.find_all('td',class_ = 'table-body__cell u-center-text')
match_records2
for i in match_records2:
    a = int(i.text.replace(',', ''))
    if a < 50:
        records.append(a)
print(records)
```

Comment: @Rahulrvz Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers !